# select all checkbox datatable trigger

Tags: jquery, checkbox, datatables

I've been currently struggling with this problem for days. The problem is how can I makes the 'click' on the select all checkbox on thead of datatables to trigger something (in this case, a "disabled" class for my buttons)?

I've makes the trigger work when user 'click' the checkbox one by one, but I can't make it works when user click the select all checkbox. Please help me, thankyou in advance.

This is my Datatables script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            table = $('#em').DataTable({
                "scrollY": "45vh",
                "scrollX": true,
                "scrollCollapse": true,
                "paging": false,

                "responsive": true,

                "aaSorting": [1, 'desc'],
                "iDisplayLength": 5,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Eromo_Web/inv?act=getAll",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "dataSrc": ""
                },
                "columnDefs": [
                    {
                        'targets': 0,
                        'checkboxes': {
                            'selectRow': true
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "columns": [
                    {"data": null},
                    {"data": "CODE"},
                    {"data": "TYPE"},
                    {"data": "NAME"},
                    {"data": "KIND"},
                    {"data": "MERK"},
                    {"data": "MODEL_TYPE"},
                    {"data": "LOC"},
                    {"data": "BUY_DATE"},
                    {"data": "USERNAME"},
                    {"data": "DESCR"},
                    {"data": "RFRGRNT"},
                    {"data": "MANF"},
                    {"data": "COUNTRY"}
                ]
            });
```

My current click trigger:

```
//getting ID on checkbox click
            $('#em').on('change', null, function () {
                if (table.column(0).checkboxes.selected().length > 0) {
                    $('#generateqrcode').attr('disabled', false);
                } else {
                    $('#generateqrcode').attr('disabled', true);
                }
                if (table.column(0).checkboxes.selected().length === 1) {
                    ID = "";
                    $.each(table.column(0).checkboxes.selected(), function (key, value) {
                        ID = value["CODE"];
                    });
                    $('#update').attr('disabled', false);
                    $('#delete').attr('disabled', false);
                } else {
                    $('#update').attr('disabled', true);
                    $('#delete').attr('disabled', true);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou for the answer. Sorry for the late reply, I found my problem, it is because I use the property `"scrollY": "45vh",` and `"scrollX": true`. If I deactivated it, the "selectAll" checkbox can be triggered easily. I don't know why tho.

This is my final code:

```
table = $('#em').DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Eromo_Web/inv?act=getAll",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "dataSrc": ""
                },
                "columnDefs": [
                    {
                        'targets': 0,
                        'checkboxes': {
                            'selectRow': false
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "columns": [
                    {"data": null},
                    {"data": "CODE"},
                    {"data": "TYPE"},
                    {"data": "NAME"},
                    {"data": "KIND"},
                    {"data": "MERK"},
                    {"data": "MODEL_TYPE"},
                    {"data": "LOC"},
                    {"data": "BUY_DATE"},
                    {"data": "USERNAME"},
                    {"data": "DESCR"},
                    {"data": "RFRGRNT"},
                    {"data": "MANF"},
                    {"data": "COUNTRY"}
                ],
                "paging": false,
                "responsive": true,
                "aaSorting": [1, 'desc'],
                "iDisplayLength": 5
            });
```

And this:

```
//                getting ID on checkbox click
                $('#em').on('change', null, function () {
                    if (table.column(0).checkboxes.selected().length > 0) {
                        $('#generateqrcode').attr('disabled', false);
                    } else {
                        $('#generateqrcode').attr('disabled', true);
                    }
                    if (table.column(0).checkboxes.selected().length === 1) {
                        ID = "";
                        $.each(table.column(0).checkboxes.selected(), function (key, value) {
                            ID = value["CODE"];
                        });
                        $('#update').attr('disabled', false);
                        $('#delete').attr('disabled', false);
                    } else {
                        $('#update').attr('disabled', true);
                        $('#delete').attr('disabled', true);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```js
$('#em').on('init.dt', function(){
    $('#em thead th input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(e) {   
        alert('Clicked on "Select all"');   
    });
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/snqw56dw/466/) for code and demonstration.

However if you're using row selection I recommend handling [`select`](https://datatables.net/reference/event/select) and [`deselect`](https://datatables.net/reference/event/deselect) events.

```js
$('#example').on('select.dt', function(){
   alert('Row selected');
});

$('#example').on('deselect.dt', function(){
   alert('Row deselected');
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/snqw56dw/467/) for code and demonstration.

In the future release of [jQuery DataTables Checkboxes](http://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/) plug-in we will add event generation for selecting all checkboxes.